# Como armazenar um array em uma string?

Tags: c#

Exemplo:

```
string x;
string[] y = {"5", "0","0","5","5"};
x = "50055"
```

quero juntar tudo em uma variável.
Vou armazenar em uma variavel nao imprimir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Só usar o Join

```
    string[] y = {"5", "0","0","5","5"};
    string x = string.Join("",y);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Veja no .NetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4exn35

Documentação: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar o [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) quando precisar de um separador. Assim:

```
string[] nomes = {"Vinicius", "Rovann", "Anderson"};
return string.Join(";", nomes);
// Saída: "Vinicius;Rovann;Anderson"
```

Se quer concatenar um array de strings em uma única string, pode utilizar o [`String.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a6d350wd(v=vs.110).aspx). Veja:

```
string[] arr = {"1", "2", "3"};
return string.Concat(arr);
// Saída: "123"
```